# Wordpress: using WP_query() and Advanced Custom Fields in function.php

Tags: php, hook, custom-post-type, wordpress

I got stuck with subj. I wrote a function that gets certain fields of posts (the 'advanced custom fields' plugin was used for the fields) with custom type 'opt', pushes it in an array, encodes it to json and updates .json file.

```
function opt_update() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'opt'
    );
    $opt_array = array();
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();
        $good_type_array = array();
        while (have_rows('type')): the_row();
            $type_name = get_sub_field('type_name');
            array_push($good_type_array, $type_name);
        endwhile;
        array_push($opt_array, array(
            'name'      => get_the_title(),
            'good_type' => $good_type_array,
            'price'     => get_field('price')
        ));
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/blablabla/json/data.json', raw_json_encode($opt_array));
}

function raw_json_encode($input) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/',
        function ($matches) {
            return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$matches[1]),'UTF-8','UTF-16');
        },
        json_encode($input)
    );
}
```

It works perfectly if I call the function, for example, on the main page:

```
opt_update();
```

But what I need is to execute the function when I publish/update the 'opt' custom post. I tried to use that hook:

```
add_action('publish_opt', 'opt_update', 10, 2);
```

... but it doesn't work at all. Although it's not a problem of the hook, if I put instead of 'opt_update' an another function, for example:

```
 add_action('publish_opt', 'mail_me', 10, 2);
```

... it sends me an e-mail message as it is supposed to. 
Where am I wrong?

UPD: Tried to do it with general wordpress posts and simplier code... still writes the file only after I press the 'update' button for the second time

```
function opt_update($ID, $post) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post'
        );
        $opt_array = array();
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();
        array_push($opt_array, array(
            'price' => get_field('price')
        ));
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/blablabla/json/data.json', raw_json_encode($opt_array));
    }
    add_action('publish_post', 'opt_update', 10, 2);
```

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work at all" what do you mean? it doesn't write the file, or it does but it's empty?

Comment: It doesn't write the file.

Comment: have you tried removing everything except the file_put_contents and just write a file with test data in it? To filter out the possibility of some internal WP process interfering I mean

Comment: Kai, I've just tried it and it writed the file. The array was $opt_array = array(NULL => 'zero',1    => 'one',2    => 'two'); and it writed {"":"zero","1":"one","2":"two"} in .json

Comment: After a few more tries I figured out that it DOES write the file, but only if I change the title somehow. If I change data in the custom fields alone, it doesn't update json.

Comment: More details: the function writes the file even if I change data only in the custom fields, but does it with a delay. For example, if I change number in a custom field to '123' and press the 'update' button, then change it to '1234' and press the button again, after the second time it'll write '123' value in the file.

Comment: are you updating everytime the custom post or just the custom field? for the latter use the [`updated_opt_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_%28meta_type%29_meta) hook

Comment: The custom post; I need to json be generated each time I publish a new custom post or edit an existing one.

Comment: Tried to do it with general wordpress posts and simplier code... still writes the file only after I press the 'update' button for the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acf/save_post hook does the trick